# Explanation of basic c to assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I've been trying so hard to learn how to accurately decipher what an `assembly` program is doing in comparison to the same `c` program .

For example:
**c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main() {

int joe = 26;

}
```

**assembly**

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
xor    %eax,%eax

movl   $0x1a,-0x4(%rbp)
pop    %rbp
retq
```

Can someone help me map out this really trivial program I wrote?

Thank you

Comment: It creates a local variable (on the function's stack frame) whose value is 26, and then returns. Precisely the same thing as what's in the C code.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar - would you mind writing an answer, explaining in more detail? Thank you!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Assembler code doesn't map precisely to c# / c++ / c code.

As it stands the code creates a reserved place in memory, pushes a val into it (1a is hexadecimal), then deletes it from memory. It's doing a lot of what happens in the 'background' that a higher language hides from you.

push %rbp onto the stack:

```
push   %rbp
```

moves whatever's in the memory at %rbp to %rsp:

```
mov    %rsp,%rbp
```

xor is a logical operation, the answer is 0. This initialises the memory  and is like you explicitly doing `int joe = 0` which is the default value for an int in c. Why not move 0 into the var? Probably because an xor is faster than moving a value into a place in memory:

```
xor    %eax,%eax
```

moves / loads a value of 1a (hexadecimal) into rdp

```
movl   $0x1a,-0x4(%rbp)
```

remove rbp from the stack:

```
pop    %rbp
```

exit:

```
retq
```

Comment: is 1a the value of 26?  Can you explain more detail line, by line? I would appreciate it so much!

Comment: This doesn't explain what the `-0x4(%rbp)` does, nor how `retq` works. Essentially you've commented some code you copied from the OP - that's not an answer.

Comment: @user3728501 Yes it does, at a level the questioner understood. I actually started to explain about the moving, but felt it was off-topic for this level of question

Comment: @user3791372 Since this site is supposed to present information for future readers not just the OP, perhaps you would like to update your question?

Comment: Great explanation, this definitely helps. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3728501 Answers can't meet all users expectations. If you have a question following this, then ask a related question. Not all answers should go down to the electron / transistor level!

Comment: @user3791372 Perhaps you should address EOF's concerns

Comment: The problem with this answer isn't that it doesn't "go down to the electron  / transistor level", it's that there is only a single sentence in it that is unquestionably correct, and that sentence is trivial.